# background-size doesn't fit element

Tags: css, element

I've tried to make a background to fit page’s height using CSS3 background-size but it works only for width, but not height.

I intended to make this background image fit 100% of page’s width and height even while breaking its ratio, I don’t see the problem since I use background-size:100% 100%; and

> [The percentage is relative to the width or height of the area given by 'background-origin'](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size)

(Any value for background-origin changes nothing)

I need some hints about why can't I make the background height to fit `<body>`? And how could I do that?

Here's a part of my css:

```
html {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
body {
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 2em;
    background:#474747 url(../images/bg.jpg) 100% 0 no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%; /* raaaaaah */
    font-family:Cambria,serif;
    min-width:910px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: you can test on http://matthecat.com/v2/blog.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over complicating. I don't know what all the other css code is for. I don't think some those even do anything.

```
body {
    background:#474747 url(http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/rabbit.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

this code works perfect for me.

I'm not really sure why you would want to do this anyway. There are much better ways to set the background of your page. You could use `background-repeat:repeat-y` for an bg slice to fill the top portion, and use a gradient image that blends into the bg color (#474747). Or if it is a texture, you could just do a full repeat. What kind of image are you trying to use this with?

Comment: I think a link was missing ^^ You can test here : http://matthecat.com/v2/blog.html

Comment: remove "height:100%" from the html selector, problem solved :)

Comment: I was using the rabbit picture from the other example to test :)

Also, you should check out Firebug. There is both a Firefox and now a Chrome version, if you use either of those browsers (you should). It lets you play with html/css changes in your browser. Chrome actually has a built in inspector that works quite well also, but I like Firebug better.

Comment: Thanks =D But I must let it to keep the footer at the bottom of the page if content doesn't fill page's height =/ And I know I can edit properties with inspectors, but what properties must I change?? ^^'

Comment: Removing the html selector doesn't move the footer for me at all. As long as the footer is the last thing in your html, it will always be at the bottom. If you want to set a min-height, put it either in the container or content div's style, not on body or html. I would remove the 'html' selector totally, and get rid of the 'min-height/width' and 'position' on the body tag.

Comment: Try to hide div.content with display:none; you'll see the problem ^^ Thanks anyway =)

Comment: There are several little small problems causing this, too much for a comment. If you want some more help email me :)

Comment: Ok, how can I get your mail? ^^' If you want you can use "Formulaire" to send me your email adress:http://matthecat.com/contact.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the source from this page... http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/background.html

Comment: I cannot use a fixed background because the scroll occures lags.